# If I quit during a mission, will I resume at the last checkpoint or before I started?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

At the end of my gaming session last night, I went to try and save and realized that there didn't appear to be an option.  I'm assuming the game's autosave is all I get, like it or not.

If I quit the game during a mission, will I start back up at the last checkpoint I passed, or do I have to start the mission over from the beginning?  Sometimes the missions chain into each other (or I don't realize I've started a new one) so I frequently don't have time to finish what I started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will start from the last checkpoint reached in the memory.

Just confirmed this in game on Sequence 8, Memory 1, after completing the first part, getting Checkpoint Reached, exiting, and loading it back up.

Answer (score 0):

I do think you restart the sequence.

Check your ADN for that. They are the equivalent of the missions.

For the saving, the game does it automatically everytime you buy/get money from banks/complete an objective.