# Can a body be lifted from a parapet?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I have been playing revelations recently and was doing the quest where the minstrels have to be knocked out and dropped into the haystack. I made a mistake in the aim and now his body lies on a parapet. I am unable to pick it up from there. Is there a way to lift him or something? any pointers? I don't want to restart the memory as I will have to travel from far and be undetected too.

Comment: Can you try tossing stuff at the body (knives, bombs) and force the physics to drop it off?

Comment: tried bombs no luck

Comment: Well, aside from restarting the mission, I can't think of any other thing. IF you quit your game and reload your save, you'll just have to play the mission from the last checkpoint.

Comment: That's how it worked in the last game, at least

Comment: JohnoBoy is correct, It works that way in [this game](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40247/if-i-quit-during-a-mission-will-i-resume-at-the-last-checkpoint-or-before-i-sta) as well.

Comment: So did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you quit your game and reload your save, you'll just have to play the mission from the last checkpoint.
 as suggested by @JohnoBoy